# How to display values within pie chart sector

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using `JFreeChart` to create pie charts. Values are displayed outside pie chart sectors as labels. I want to display the values *within* the pie sectors. How can I achieve this. Please can any one help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`setSimpleLabels()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#setSimpleLabels(boolean)), as shown [here](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html); [`org.jfree.chart.demo.PieChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/182987da8db9531ceb44af591835a6124fb303b9/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo2/PieChartDemo1.java#L63) is a good starting point.

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setSimpleLabels(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `createPieChart3D` to create Pie chart, following URL will be helpful to you.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartPieChart3DDemo1.htm
What I know is, showing values inside is default feature of the chart. If you're unable to do so it seems that you have changed the default way.

Comment: The labels are shown outside by default, as seen in [`org.jfree.chart.demo.PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html).